# Convert from Base64 String to PNG File

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying to convert a base64 encoded string to an image object using the method below.

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    console.log('Starting gotFileWriter');
    writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };

    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    //        console.log('height: ' + cb_canvas.height);
    //        console.log('width: ' + cb_canvas.width);
    Signaturebase64 = cb_canvas.toDataURL();

    //I need to save the base64 string to a PNG image on the Phone here.  
    writer.write(Signaturebase64 );

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    $.mobile.changePage("#MyJob");
    console.log('Finished gotFileWriter');
}
```

The line:

```
Signaturebase64 = cb_canvas.toDataURL();
```

Works as expected and gives me back my base64 string.

What I would like to do now is to convert it to an image file on the phone's persistent storage.

The following line is writing the base64 string to the storage but what I want it to do is save it as a PNG file instead:

```
writer.write(filedata);
```

Comment: If the base64 string is just encoded image data, just decode it and write it to a file with an image extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the PhoneGap FileWriter to write binary data. You'd need to write a plugin to send your base64 encoded data to the native side, encode it into binary then write it using native code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any links or tutorials for something like this?

Comment: Check out the plugins info at: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins also take a look at the phonegap source code to see how we do the file writer and you can add some code to do the base64 decode before writing.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll let you know how I get on with this on Monday.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald i have tried using `writer.write(atob(IM.fileReceived));` where `IM.fileReceived` is my encoded string of an image but after writing to a file i am not able to view it , can you tell me where am i getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the base64 back to binary. Here is an example: http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/