# Cannot decode base64 uncaught error - HTML canvas element to sd card

Tags: cordova, canvas, base64, android-sdcard, filewriter

I'm trying to store a signature (which is drawn on the canvas element) on the device's sd card. I'm using eclipse + phonegap(version 1.7.0).

I came across the following link -

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/I23hrgFOgN8

I tried the following code -

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var writer = new FileWriter("/mnt/sdcard/sign.png");
ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
var img64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
var img = atob(img64);
navigator.notification.alert(img64);
writer.write(img64);
```

But I encounter the following error - Uncaught Error: Cannot decode base64 (at the line where I have used atob).

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible directly:

[Convert from Base64 String to PNG File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840742/convert-from-base64-string-to-png-file)

Check this library which does the conversion locally - [base64 decoding in javascript](http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/).

Comment: I went through the library. But the problem is that I WILL have to use the `toDataURL` method before decoding it. When I use the `toDataURL` method, there is no data returned (I checked this using the alert method). Is there any alternative to `toDataURL`? I guess once I'm able to store the data in the Base64 string format, I'll be able to use the library.

Comment: a simple example with empty canvas works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/WheG7/. Are you sure that your canvas is initialized properly or not getting cleared

Comment: Now I'm facing the following error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: Uint8Array is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/Scripts/base64-binary.js:33`

Comment: I think Uint8Array is not supported on Android before version 3. http://bugs.owncloud.org/thebuggenie/owncloud/issues/oc-395. Any alternative?

Comment: try this - http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html i m not completely sure that this will work but better to check

Comment: Data is getting stored now but I can't still open the image. Please check if the data which is getting stored is in the correct format and everything is correct in my javascript - http://www.4shared.com/folder/EQhIVsoN/Sign.html.

Comment: I think the problem lies with the `toDataURL` method. The data getting stored is always the same. The `toDataURL` method is not supported in Android versions below 4. So I used this - http://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/wiki/FirstSteps.

Comment: No. Same data is getting stored in all the cases. But I think that won't be a problem on version 3 and above. My major concern is whether the data is getting stored in the correct format. Can you help me with that?

Comment: can you put your save function which i can check??

Comment: I've used `FileWriter` to create the .png file and I write using the `write` function. You can see the function as well as the data which is obtained here - http://www.4shared.com/folder/EQhIVsoN/Sign.html

Comment: can you put these files in `gist.github.com`

Comment: I still feel that the data is not being stored as it should by the `toDataURL` method.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3032724. Check the raw version to see how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Well toDataUrl is just a stub on Android up to version 4 so it actually doesn't do anything. So the value of "img64" is probably null and to make mattes worse you can write binary data using the PhoneGap FileWriter anyway. So you are going to need to figure out a different way to do this.

However, I do know someone who has successfully integrated [Signature Capture for Android](http://www.binarysolutions.biz/p/signature-capture-for-android.html) into their PhoneGap app by calling it as an intent. So that'd be the route I'd take.

Comment: I went through the link you recommended. Is there any way to save the canvas as an image by just using JavaScript?

Comment: Any alternative for `toDataURL`?

Comment: A plugin was written once upon a time but it'll probably need to be updated: http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ryangillespie.com%2Fdownloads%2FCanvasPlugin.java&ei=19LxT_DqHqbk6QGZ27CWBg&usg=AFQjCNFZYI_EnFhRQLt_S8vNS2yelPXk3g&sig2=vJPn3hIpKCmfXILQQ7ei6g

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. I'll just wait till I get an Android device above version 3.0 and try testing on that. It should work fine on versions above 3.0, right?

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked. The toDataUrl method for canvas seems to be implemented in the 3.0 emulator at least.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon said, this is not possible on Android under version 4. The rest of your code is probably correct, although I haven't had a chance to test it.

A idea that came to mind was read the canvas pixel for pixel and then create a binary yourself. [This Library](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) has a function built in to convert a canvas to BMP. From there you might be able to save it as a file, like you tried with the PNG before.

Again, this is just some brainstorming, I haven't tested anything and I would personally also go with the solution Simon came up with, as it's easier and most likely also a lot more stable.

Comment: If I use the following line `navigator.notification.alert(img)` instead of `navigator.notification.alert(img64)` I get an alert message displaying - data:,. But now I'm wondering this is because the toDataURL method is useless under version 4. I also tried the library you asked me to. In that case, neither do I get any alert message nor is the file created on the sdcard.

Comment: Okay. Well, it was worth trying. Then I don't have any further ideas other then implementing a native Android-library for this as a plugin in Phonegap.